# sub-component with forwardRef

Tags: reactjs, react-functional-component

I'm making a simple UI component and its sub-components.

```
/* Checkbox.jsx */
const Checkbox = React.forwardRef((props, ref)=>{
  return (
    <input type="checkbox" ref={ref} />
  ) 
});
const Group = (props) => (<div>Group</div>);

Checkbox.Group = Group;
export default Checkbox;
```

it doesn't work with `React.forwardRef()`.

Without `React.forwardRef()`, this code works well but I want to use `forwardRef()` also.

I'd like to use it like this

```
function App(){
  return (
    <div>
      <Checkbox />
      <Checkbox.Group />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you say its not working. What do you mean? Because it does work for me . Here is a codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-shtern-vq7sy?file=/src/App.js

Comment: It throws an error. `Property 'Group' does not exist on type 'ForwardRefExoticComponent`

Comment: Do you use Typescript?

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Yes, I am using ts .

Comment: There is an issue regarding this on github: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/34757

Answer (score 3):

A few years later, but I stumbled upon this when I encountered this issue myself. Luckily, `ivan-kleshnin` on GitHub provided [this method](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/34757#issuecomment-894053907) for making this work. I've adapted their answer to fit your question and add more context.

### Defining the components

For example, let's say you have a checkbox component located in `src/components/checkbox.jsx`:

1. Create the main component like normal.

   ```js
   const Checkbox = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
     return <input type="checkbox" ref={ref} />
   })
   ```
2. Create the sub-components like normal.

   ```js
   const Group = (props) => (<div>Group</div>)
   ```

   These children can **also** use `forwardRef()` if needed.

   ```js
   const Group = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
     return <div ref={ref}>Group</div>
   })
   ```
3. Assign sub-components to the parent and return a new object. The `Namespace` name isn't special, it's just a way to clarify what's going on and prevent local name clashes.

   ```js
   const CheckboxNamespace = Object.assign(Checkbox, { Group })
   ```

   Alternatively, to assign multiple sub-components at a time, extend the second argument object of `Object.assign()`:

   ```js
   const CheckboxNamespace = Object.assign(
     Checkbox, { Group, AnotherSubComponent }
   )
   ```
4. Lastly, export the namespace as the desired parent component name. Again, this is done to prevent namespace clashes.

   ```js
   export { CheckboxNamespace as Checkbox }
   ```

### Using the components

With the above, you can now use the sub-components of components with `forwardRef()` like you were originally looking for:

```js
import { Checkbox } from "~/components/checkbox"

function App(){
  const checkboxRef = useRef()

  return (
    <div>
      <Checkbox ref={checkboxRef} />
      <Checkbox.Group />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try exporting them separately:

```
/* Checkbox.jsx */
const Checkbox = React.forwardRef((props, ref)=>{
  return (
    <input type="checkbox" ref={ref} />
  ) 
});
const Group = (props) => (<div>Group</div>);

export funcs = {
Checkbox,
Group
}

export default funcs;
```

and in the parent:

```
import funcs from './Checkbox.jsx';

function App(){
  return (
    <div>
      <funcs.Checkbox />
      <funcs.Group />
    </div>
  )
}
```